# MySQL:multiples condiciones a diferentes columnas en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: iCAPTURA DE LA CONSULTA]

Deseo que esta consulta me salgo solo en una fila:

```
 select (case month(p.fechaVent)
 when 1 then sum(p.totalVent)
end) AS "ENERO",(case month(p.fechaVent)
 when 2 then sum(p.totalVent)
 end) AS "FEBRERO"
 from proformas p
   group by  month(p.fechaVent)
```

Como se puede puede ver en la imagen adjuntada me sale con valores nulos,deseo 
que los valores nulos no salgan y solo los datos me salgan en una fila,e pensado en hacerlo con una especie de subconsulta a cada columnas que agrego pero la verdad que estoy buscando info pero no encuentro lo que necesito,un empujón por favor.

Comment: Sería conveniente que edites tu pregunta copiando el código de tu consulta SQL, y reduciendo el uso de las mayúsculas ya que es muy molesto a la hora de leer.

Comment: estas haciendo un group by month.. apuesto a que te salen 12 filas...

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: si,me salen 12 filas pero osea no se como limitar eso.

Comment: es que todo el query esta mal.. cuando haces el case, se evalua linea por linea del resultado. si agrupas por mes, quiere decir que de plano vas a tener 12 filas, para los meses que queres.. lo que vos queres hacer deberias resolverlo en una consulta que transponga los resultados, pq estas buscando de la misma tabla 12 columnas distintas. estas seguro que queres eso?

Comment: cierto,es que en un principio deseaba verlos en una misma columnas,y logre hacer eso,pero me lio cuando ahora deseo otorgarles una columna a cada mes.

Answer (score 1):

En ese caso solo debes valerte de una subconsulta.

```
select sum(ifnull(ENERO,0)) as ENERO, sum(ifnull(FEBRERO,0)) as FEBRERO -- Los otros meses...
from (
 select 
   (case month(p.fechaVent) when 1 then sum(p.totalVent) end) AS "ENERO",
   (case month(p.fechaVent) when 2 then sum(p.totalVent) end) AS "FEBRERO"
   -- Los otros meses..
 from proformas p 
 group by month(p.fechaVent)
) as subconsulta;
```

---

### Explicando:

```
select 
  (case month(p.fechaVent) when 1 then sum(p.totalVent) end) AS "ENERO",
  (case month(p.fechaVent) when 2 then sum(p.totalVent) end) AS "FEBRERO"
  -- Los otros meses..
  from proformas p 
  group by month(p.fechaVent)
```

El código anterior realiza la consulta que propones en la pregunta, retornando una tabla mas o menos así.

```
+-----------+-----------+------+                                                                                                                                                                                        
| ENERO     | FEBRERO   | ...  |                                                                                                                                                                                        
+-----------+-----------+------+                                                                                                                                                                                        
| 100.000   | NULL      | ...  |                                                                                                                                                                                        
+-----------+-----------+------+                                                                                                                                                                                        
| NULL      | 65.000    | ...  |                                                                                                                                                                                        
+-----------+-----------+------+                                                                                                                                                                                        
| NULL      | NULL      | ...  |                                                                                                                                                                                        
+-----------+-----------+------+                                                                                                                                                                                        
| NULL      | NULL      | ...  |                                                                                                                                                                                        
+-----------+-----------+------+                                                                                                                                                                                        
| NULL      | NULL      | ...  |                                                                                                                                                                                        
+-----------+-----------+------+                                                                                                                                                                                        
| ...       | ...       | ...  |                                                                                                                                                                                        
+-----------+-----------+------+
```

Ahora ya tienes una nueva tabla y por tanto puedes realizar una consulta sobre ella, solo bastaría con sumar las filas de cada columna, pero sin embargo debes considerar que:

```
sum(ENERO) -- El resultado será NULL 
-- puesto  que 100.000 + NULL + ... + NULL = NULL
```

Entonces solo debes convertir a cero (0) todo lo que sea null

```
sum(ifnull(ENERO,0)) -- Siempre se completa primero la función interna 
-- Ahora 100.000 + (0) + ... + (0) = 100.000
```

Entonces considerando lo anterior

```
select sum(ifnull(ENERO,0)) as ENERO, sum(ifnull(FEBRERO,0)) as FEBRERO -- Los otros meses...
from (...) -- Donde (...) es la tabla resultado de la consulta que describimos arriba
```

Veras que la tabla que describimos arriba "no existe realmente", puesto que es  una consulta, ahora el resultado de una consulta es una tabla así que puede consultarse sobre ella, por tanto lo único que esta restando es darle un nombre `alias` a aquella consulta solo como por cumplir buenas practicas.

```
select sum(ifnull(ENERO,0)) as ENERO, sum(ifnull(FEBRERO,0)) as FEBRERO -- Los otros meses...
from (...) as subconsulta;
```

Espero que sea un poco ilustrativo para ti, aquí puedes encontrar mas información http://mysql.localhost.net.ar/doc/refman/5.0/es/subqueries.html.

Comment: no lo probe, pero esto evita que le salgan 12 filas?

Comment: ¿Quieres mantener las 12 filas?

Comment: OP no queria eso, por eso pregunto

Comment: gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: sin hacerte tanto lio me resolvistes la pregunta.me falta profundizar subconsultas,siempre le lie x las subconsultas.

Comment: La consulta interna «Tu consulta» trae 12 filas, y la externa suma esas 12 filas dejando solo una.

Comment: si gracias aun sigo analizando tu codigo xD.algun lugar o pagina que me recomiendes para estudiar las subconsultas,me has impresionado xD

Comment: He modificado la respuesta, con una referencia.

Comment: Gracias amigo tratare de profundizar en el tema.